# Material UI: cannot use import statement outside a module - Select dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui

Heeey, My question is the following:

I have this project, made with NextJS + React with node. Straight to the point, my app works well, except when reloading a page with a Select from Material UI. The code that matters in that page is:

```
<Select defaultValue='#' onChange={e => setCommunityCode(e.target.value)} labelId='communityLabel'>
   <MenuItem value='#' hidden={true}></MenuItem>
      {communities.map(community => (
          <MenuItem value={community.id} key={community.id}>
             {community.id + ' - ' + community.name}
          </MenuItem>
   ))}
</Select>
```

Now, my page works great, up until pressing F5 or reloading the page with the "Relaod" button of my browser.
Then, it show the following message:

"SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module". If I start digging (not much though) it appears the error comes from a dependency from node_modules, it being from @mui/material and being Select.

The way I import Select is:

```
import Select from '@mui/material/Select/Select';
```

[The image showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeYSu.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not importing **Select** properly .
Do this instead :

```
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
// or
import { Select } from '@mui/material';
```

Comment: Thank you! Visual Studio code was showing me an incorrect import, and I didn't check if it was completely ok.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with the import statement ?

Comment: Yes, it was the import statement! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

MUI v5, Grid2 component, for me solved in this way:

**incorrect:**

```
import Grid from "@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2/Grid2";
```

**correct:**

```
import Grid from "@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2";
```